# Immersive mode - only hide status bar + rehide status bar after some time without user interaction

Tags: android, fullscreen, android-fullscreen, android-statusbar, android-immersive

I have an activity with 2 toolbars, one at the top and one at bottom. I use inversive mode and this works fine now, it allows the user to drag down the status bar...

The problem, the status bar is never hidden again, after it was dragged down...

I found a few solutions here, but I just could not get it working. Either the status bar is shown over my view, or it messes up if I open the overflow menu or it just does not get hidden again...

This is what I currently use:

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    enableFullScreenMode();
}

private void enableFullScreenMode()
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16)
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    else
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
//                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
//                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        );
}
```

**What I want**

- always fullscreen until the user drags down the status bar
- after for example 3s the status bar should be hidden again, if it was not opened
- after closing the status bar it should be hidden again
- when opening my overflow menu in the toolbar, the status bar should NOT show up

Comment: german comments...

Comment: Removed the single comment... Nit-picky and non productive comment though...

Comment: to be fair - im working on the same problem and will post you the solution when i found it ;)

Comment: Would be nice. Currently I've implemented a solution that's working, but the statusbar is not hiding automatically anymore (I don't know when it's shown so I can't trigger calling the hide function). So it stays visible until the user clicks on the screen again... Which is fine

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, [Sticker immersive](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive#sticky-immersive) mode.

As the doc says:

> "The bars automatically disappear after a few seconds of no interaction or as soon as the user touches or gestures anywhere outside the system bars."

```java
private void hideSystemUI() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

//1.put this after on click.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        hideSystemUI();
    }
}

private void hideSystemUI() {
    // Enables regular immersive mode.
    // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
    // Or for "sticky immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}
```

//2.Remove "android:fitsSystemWindows="true"" from everywhere from you layout.

//3.Add hideSystemUI() in onResumes like this ,(for, auto re hiding status and bottom navigation ).

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    hideSystemUI();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener
        (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
        // Note that system bars will only be "visible" if none of the
        // LOW_PROFILE, HIDE_NAVIGATION, or FULLSCREEN flags are set.
        if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
            // TODO: The system bars are visible. Make any desired
            // adjustments to your UI, such as showing the action bar or
            // other navigational controls.
        } else {
            // TODO: The system bars are NOT visible. Make any desired
            // adjustments to your UI, such as hiding the action bar or
            // other navigational controls.
        }
    }
});
```